# Android R : API 30 : System bar visibility change call backs

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to make my app a full screen app. On Api levels 29 and below, I am using `onSystemUIVisibilityChange` listener to handle visibility of certain views in my activity when the app is in full screen. But on api level 30, is there any similar callback to know when system bars(status bar and navigation bar) visibility changes? Since `onSystemUIVisibilityChange` is deprecated for API level 29 and above.

I am aware of `activity.window.insetsController.show(WindowInsets.Type.systemBars())` to show and hide System bars. What I need is a callback when system bar visibility changes.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener) you can set a listener using
[`View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener((view: View, window:WindowInsets) -> WindowInsets)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener)
and then in the listener you can check whether the system bars are visible or not using [`WindowInsets.isVisible(Int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsets#isVisible(int)). Like so:

```kotlin
private val onWindowInsetApplied: (view: View, window:WindowInsets) -> WindowInsets = { view, windowInsets ->
    val areSystemBarsVisible = windowInsets.isVisible(WindowInsets.Type.systemBars())
    //Do something
    windowInsets
}

fun setListener() {
    View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener(onWindowInsetApplied)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Java developers, this is the `java` version of `@ Kyzer Soze` answer

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {

    decorView.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(new View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
        @Override
        public WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(View v, WindowInsets insets) {

            if (insets.isVisible(WindowInsets.Type.systemBars())) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "system bars are Visible",    
                                                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "system bars are Invisible", 
                                                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            return insets;
        }
    });

}
```

Make sure not to call `setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener` in below API-30, as it will raise runtime exception

Comment: To avoid the runtime exception you can use the `AndroidX` method: `ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(decorView, listener)`